# Displaying a b-table with different arrays inside other arrays in Bootstrap.vue

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, vue.js, bootstrap-vue

I have some data I'm trying to display in a b-table

It works fine with most data, but when I hit another array inside the referenced array, it doesn't render properly.

So I tripped over this markup

```
<template v-slot:cell(name)="data">
   <b class="text-info">{{ data.value.last.toUpperCase() }}</b>, <b>{{ data.value.first}}</b>
</template>
```

From bootstraps' [table documentation](https://bootstrap-vue.org/docs/components/table#custom-data-rendering).

That's great! Unfortunately, I can't get data out properly.

The issue is that the data contains different types of arrays depending on what is being used:

```
"range": {
        "type": "point",
        "distance": {
           "type": "touch"
         }
},
```

and

```
"range": {
     "type": "point",
      "distance": {
       "type": "feet",
       "amount": 150
    }
},
```

So I can easily retrieve the type variable, as it's always there, but in case distance.type and distance.amount exists, I'd want to display that as well. Unfortunately this causes an error - because sometimes it doesn't contain amount.

```
<b-table striped hover :items="spells">
   <template v-slot:cell(range)="rangeData">
      <b class="text-info">
         {{rangeData.item.range.distance}}, <--- this displays the content of the problematic array
         {{rangeData.item.range.distance.feet}}, <-- this causes undefined errors and fails to load
         {{rangeData.item.range.type}}  <--- this displays properly
     </b>
   </template>
</b-table>
```

So a solution I was hoping to find, was to make a conditional field, which checks if the data is reachable, if not, don't display anything. But I can't find any answers or documentation for it.

Wrapping distance.feet in a v-if still causes errors and then doesn't display anything.

Comment: {{rangeData.item.range.distance.feet}}, is it correct ? i think it should have {{rangeData.item.range.distance.type}},

Comment: type displays, because it's always there - but that's not the value I'm looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your question, you are trying to use condition to show data if available otherwise you don't want to show.

For that you simply have do as below-

```
<b class-"text-info">
   {{rangeData.item.range && rangeData.item.range.distance ? rangeData.item.range.distance: "" }},
   {{rangeData.item.range && rangeData.item.range.distance && rangeData.item.range.distance.feet ? rangeData.item.range.distance.feet: "" }},
   {{rangeData.item.range && rangeData.item.range.type ? rangeData.item.range.type: "" }}
</b>
```

Comment: I love you. This has been driving me nuts for at day. <3 Worked like a charm!